401 Unauthorized : A security token is required but the token storage is empty. SYMFONY6
i'm working with symfony 6 and react js , im trying to access the cart of the user and it works correctly when I test it with postman but it throws  this error when I test it in my frontend interface
401 Unauthorized : A security token is required but the token storage is empty.
this is my api function :
class PanierController extends AbstractController

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage) {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

  #[Route('/api/get_panier', name: 'get-panier', methods: ['GET','POST'])]

    public function getPanierContents(  TokenInterface $token , Request $request ): Response
    {
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
        if (!$token) {
            return $this->json(['message' => 'Token not found'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();
        if (!$user || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            $this->logger->error("User not found");
            return $this->json(['message' => 'User not found'], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
  error_log("User found: " . $user->getUserIdentifier());

        $panier = $user->getPanier();

        if (!$panier) {
            return $this->json(['message' => 'Panier not found'], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        $billets = $panier->getBillets();

        // Convert billets collection to array
        $billetsArray = [];
        foreach ($billets as $billet) {
            $billetsArray[] = [
                'id' => $billet->getId(),
                'date_debut_evenementt'=>$billet->getDateDebutEvenement(),
                // Add other properties you want to include
            ];
        }
    //    $serializedContents = $serializer->serialize($contents, 'json', ['groups' => 'billet']);

        return $this->json($billetsArray);
    

}
  

and this is my security.yaml config :
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\Users
        property: email

  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      lazy: true
      provider: app_user_provider
      custom_authenticator: App\Security\UsersAuthenticator
     
      logout:
        path: app_logout
        target: connexion_page
      
    login:
        stateless: true
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
      
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        jwt: ~


and this is how i am consuming it in react js :
export const fetchPanierData = (userId) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const token = getToken();
      if (!token) {
        throw new Error("No token found");
      }
      const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/get_panier`, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          
        },
      });
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_PANIER_SUCCESS", payload: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_PANIER_FAILURE",
        payload: error.response ? error.response.data : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
};


I think the problem is in my security.yaml config so if you can help me that be great
before using  TokenInterface $token  in my api function I tried with #[currentUser] but it gave me a similar problem where it worked fine in postman but kept throwing a user not found error in my frontend

Did you check your request to see if there is a security token ? is your method getToken() returning a token ?

yes it's returning a token and I am storing it in localStoarge

Narrow down the issue. Focus on either Symfony configuration or React implementation, not both.
